# Text Response Assertion on a single script in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing

I'm using JMeter 5.4.1 and I've a recording of almost 10 scripts. Its a simple sign in -> dashboard -> sign out scenario. Now I want to apply assertion only on my "dashboard" script whether it shows the "welcome" message upon successful login or not. How to apply assertion on a single script out of 10 scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Put it **as a child** of the particular HTTP Request sampler - it will be applied to this sampler only.

[image]

More information:

- [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)
- [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)